# CopyFileEx with multiple files, but only one copy dialog

Tags: c#, winapi, file-copying

I've searched the web and stackoverflow for this.

I want to copy multiple files from multiple sources to multiple destinations. I don't bother with UnauthorizedAccessExceptions yet - the files are most likely to not be in use anyway.

I can copy 1 file using CopyFileEx-Wrapper from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163851.aspx). However: I'd like the standard windows copy file dialog to appear. And I'd like to copy multiple files - not just one - by e.g. passing an array of source files and an array of destination files.

Is there a way to do this? Further more: is there a way to queue this as one task and not x separated copy operations? The reason for this is the fact that I'd like to display only one progressing dialog - from the start till the end of copying all files.

I hope my question is clear.

Thank you all very much in advance.

divStar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with the IFileOperation shell interface, available since Vista.  A managed class wrapper for this COM interface is available in the December 2007 issue of [MSDN Magazine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/msdn-magazine-issues).

The Article is titled "*.NET Matters: IFileOperation in Windows Vista*"
The sample code is still available [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/7/f279e71e-efb0-4155-873d-5554a0608523/NetMatters2007_12.exe).

Fall back on your existing code if it also needs to run on earlier versions of Windows.

Comment: Thank you :D. It does do exactly what I want it to - too bad I should check whether my application runs on Windows Vista or 7 before involving that functionality..

Answer (score 1):

Set the [`MultiSelect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect.aspx) property of your [`OpenFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) to true.