# C#: OpenFileDialog copy a file

Tags: c#, image, path, openfiledialog, file-copying

Hi I have a button with this code:

```
     OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        string percorso = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        percorso += @"\img\Articoli";
        ofd.InitialDirectory = percorso;
        ofd.Filter = "File JPEG/JPG (*.jpeg *.jpg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|File PNG (*.png)|*.png;|Tutti i files (*.*)|*.*"; 
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            tPercorso.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ofd.FileName);
            Refresh_Image();
        }
```

I need that when I select a file in the OpenFileDialog, if his path is not equal to "percorso" a MessageBox will appear: "Do you want to copy file in default path?" YES | NO if DialogResult == YES I need to copy this file to path "percorso" and select filename only like I'm doing.
Can you help me?
Regards.

Comment: Use the FileOk event to reject paths before the dialog closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care about copying the file, look no further than [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  If you want to copy the file with the standard shell progress dialog, check out [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687443/how-to-bring-up-the-built-in-file-copy-dialog).

You should also check out [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).