# How do i bring up the windows 8.1 "file copy dialogue box" (one with the pause/resume functionality) from my c# code while copying a file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, file-copying

I found a similar question here "[How to bring up the built-in File Copy dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687443/how-to-bring-up-the-built-in-file-copy-dialog)" but was not able to understand if this is possible in windows 8.1.

I am trying to develop a console application where i just want to copy a file/folder from a source to destination. I want to give the user the ability to pause/resume or cancel the file download. For this i was looking to bring up the native windows 8.1 "file copy dialogue box" where we have the pause/resume functionality built in. How can i bring it up from my c# code?

Comment: Have you tried it? Doesn't seem to have anything special in there that would make it not work on windows 8

Comment: it's mentioned there that to use it with c#, we have to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO, but it seems there is no such reference to FileIO available in the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`IFileOperation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the interface that provides this functionality, but as it is a COM interface you need to use COM interop from C#.

There's an article about it in [MSDN magazine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163304.aspx).