# file move loop and show progressbar

Tags: c#, progress

How could I show a progress bar when moving a file?

Currently I've got this:

```
 private void btnMoveFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (pathFrom != null && pathTo != null)
                {
                    if (txtRename.Text != null)
                    {
                        pathTo = pathTo + "\\" + txtRename.Text;
                    }

                    else
                    {

                        pathTo = pathTo + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(pathFrom);
                    }

                    File.Move(pathFrom, pathTo);
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Kies eerst een bestand.");
                }
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                // Wait 100 milliseconds.
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                // Report progress.
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            // Set the text.
            this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
        }
```

But because `File.Move(pathFrom, pathTo);` is not a loupe I've got no Idea how to do this.

Comment: call this method asynchronously and while is runing dispplay a loading message

Comment: If you want to display the progress of the single file-copy, you have to open 2 filesstreams and copy the bytes. This way you can calculate how far you are when copying and you can display a progress. With File.Move you can't

Comment: general advice: to make your code portable and survive future releases of the OS, better use the built-in library functions and constants to manipulate your path variables: `Path.Combine` and `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`. this is too often neglected in publicly available documentation and sample code.

Comment: @dlatikay thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the `SHFileOperation` API from shell32.
A working solution is described in this answer: [How to bring up the built-in File Copy dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687443/how-to-bring-up-the-built-in-file-copy-dialog)
It works for copy as well as for move and delete.