# How to "copy-paste" files like windows

Tags: c#, windows, copy-paste

I have a lot of files to copy, and I want to copy them like windows copy files:

first show the preparing window include the process bar, time remaining, speed, etc.), like this:

[image]

And after that the "copying" window (include the process bar, time remaining, speed, etc.), like this:

[image]

I found at MSDN forum how to copy-paste one file ([link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c913f07d-31e6-48c3-bb0a-a1f26ef19939/using-windows-copypaste-to-copy-files-from-c-application)):

> There is a system function called SHFileOperation, which has to be
>   called via “P/Invoke”. To use it in easier manner, add a reference to
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly, then try this:
>
> using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
>
> . . . .
>
> FileSystem.CopyFile( @"source file", @"destination file",
>   UIOption.AllDialogs );
>
> In order to detect whether the operation was canceled by user, use a 
>   try-catch construct and intercept OperationCanceledException

My question: How can I copy-paste a **list of files** ?

Thank you

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Sounds like a solution, but if it creates n copy-file dialogs for n files, then it's not a good one.

Comment: Perhaps this will help then. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124038/copyfileex-with-multiple-files-but-only-one-copy-dialog

Comment: @Theodoros Chatzigiannakis: Thank you, it's really look good. I'll check it

Comment: It's create n copy-file dialogs for n files... I think I'll build my own dialog. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about using a DOS command?

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe","/C copy c:\file.txt d:\");

For "executing dos commands without opening the console window" maybe this helps:
http://www.developerstation.org/2009/04/c-executing-dos-commands-without.html

Comment: It's not good for me:
1. The user not get the "prepare" windows and it's importment
2. It's not take care if file(s) exist(s) [with checkbox for all files]
3. It's not GUI